# Como trabalhar com niveis de autorização com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou montando um sistema de boletim escolar para treinar minhas habilidades em php.

E estou com dificuldade em uma parte. É o seguinte: Tenho 3 tipos de usuários: professor, admin e aluno. O professor pode colocar nota e alterar a nota, mas essa nota só é alterada caso o admin aprove. O aluno por sua vez só pode ver sua nota e solicitar alteração. Já o admin pode criar novos usuários, aprovar alteração de nota e outras N coisas.

Eu criei 3 classes até agora, a classe mãe é `usuario`, e as filhas são professor e admin, falta a dos alunos. Mas como eu trabalho esses níveis de acesso com php?

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Podes criar vários tipos de utilizador através da tua base de dados, como por exemplo um campo chamado tipo_utilizador.

Estes tipos assumem valores consoante o utilizador, por exemplo:

- tipo_utilizador = 0 (Aluno)
- tipo_utilizador = 1 (Professor)
- tipo_utilizador = 2 (Admin)

Depois no teu código em PHP podes guardar no Login do utilizador o tipo_utilizador que iniciou sessão.

Desta forma quando fores criar por exemplo uma nota podes verificar que utilizador está a tentar visualizar, por exemplo:

```
if ($tipo_utilizador == 0) { /* ALUNO - APENAS VÊ */ }
```

E por ai em diante:

```
if ($tipo_utilizador == 1) { /* PROFESSOR - FORM PARA INSERIR */ }
if ($tipo_utilizador == 2) { /* ADMIN - FORM PARA INSERIR, EDITAR, APROVAR */ }
```

Cumps,

Answer (score 2):

Bom, tentei fazer algo diferente do que faço, fiz toda a autorização baseada em token:

```
<?php

class ACL // classe para controle de acesso
{
    // retorna um token baseado no tipo do usuário, usando base64
    public static function generateToken($type)
    {
        return base64_encode('YOUR_APP_KEY'.$type);
    }

    // verifica se token recebido é de algum tipo
    public static function validToken($active, $type)
    {
        return base64_decode($active) === 'YOUR_APP_KEY'.$type;
    } 

    // em ambos coloquei também a key da aplicação para ter mais segurança
}


// array de usuários com o token de cada um
$users = [
    'aluno'         => ACL::generateToken('aluno'),
    'professor'     => ACL::generateToken('professor'),
    'administrador' => ACL::generateToken('administrador'),
];


// se o meu formulário de acesso não foi submetido eu irei exibir ele
if(count($_POST) <= 0) :

?>

<form method='post'>
    <input type='radio' name='type' value='aluno'> Aluno
    <input type='radio' name='type' value='professor'> Professor
    <input type='radio' name='type' value='administrador'> Administrador
    <input type='submit' value='Access'>
</form>

<?php
// caso o formulário de acesso tenha sido submetido
else :
    $type = $_POST['type']; // salvo o tipo de usuário

    // verifico o token do usuário com o tipo que eu já tinha definido antes, assim identifico qual usuário é
    if(ACL::validToken($users[$type], 'aluno'))
        echo 'Acessou como aluno';
    else if(ACL::validToken($users[$type], 'professor'))
        echo 'Acessou como professor';
    else if(ACL::validToken($users[$type], 'administrador'))
        echo 'Acessou como administrador';

endif;
?>
```

Para fazer isso no seu sistema, você deverá gravar ou o *token* ou o tipo de usuário no registro do mesmo no banco de dados, na hora do *login* você irá recuperar esse *token* e salvar em sessão (caso queira aplicar uma criptografia nesse *token* ficaria melhor ainda), e no seu arquivo de rotas você varia essa verificação.